# self updating drawings C#

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I am trying to make an external map for a computer game.
Therefore I have made a Forms Application with a picture box, that contains my map image.
Now I want to draw little squares onto the map using GDI. I allready got that working using `Graphics.DrawRectangle`.
Now I want to update the position of the rectangle every 0.2s.
How do I do that?

My current source (i wnt to replace the button with an auto-update):

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //choords local player
    int localX;
    int localY;
    int running;
    const int Basex = 0x05303898;
    const int Basey = 0x05303894;
    const string Game = "ac_client";
    //map drawing
    Pen aPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
    Graphics localp;



    //choords enemy

    //permission to read process memory
    const int PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010; //needed for reading memory


    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(int hProcess,
    int lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Process.GetProcessesByName(Game).Length > 0)
        {
            Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName(Game)[0];
            IntPtr procHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, false, process.Id);

            int bytesRead = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[24]; //'Hello World!' takes 12*2 bytes because of Unicode 


            // 0x0046A3B8 is the address where I found the string, replace it with what you found
            ReadProcessMemory((int)procHandle, Basex, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead);
            localX = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
            LBlocalx.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimal(localX)));


            ReadProcessMemory((int)procHandle, Basey, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead);
            localY = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
            LBlocaly.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimal(localY)));


            localp = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            localp.DrawRectangle(aPen, (Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimal(localX))))/1000), (Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimal(localY))))/1000), 10, 10);

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error! Process not running.");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please provide more information. Where are you storing the squares that are drawn? Show us your current code and what you attempted to do. Basically, you'll need to clear the drawing each "frame" and then draw all the squares again at the appropriate positions. We can't help more unless you're more specific

Comment: Updated my post. I basically want to rteplace the button_click with an automatic update...

Comment: Are the squares to be drawn over the map or shall they be drawn into the map, changing the map pixels? - Usually you would use a timer, change the data of the grahpic items you want to draw and invalidate the pb. In its paint event you draw your list of items.. this is how to draw on the surface.

Comment: They shall be drawn over the map.

Comment: Don't store that local graphic localp.  Graphic objects are temporary objects you get from a paint event or from the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you store two time variables(`DateTime`) one that has the time when you started checking for that 2 second difference, another with current time and on the beginning of every iteration you verify if the difference  of both times is 2 seconds. Remember, the first variable is the one that has the time when the difference was 2 seconds or when you first started checking for that difference.

You could also use the `Timer` class and set a timer that on ever 2secs do something.

Timer class reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You could use threading to check the difference if you don't have a drawing loop.

Comment: If you're planning on making a game, you need a draw loop where you'll be able to draw/update any image, value, etc. I was a bit confused after reading your code. I wasn't really sure if you were trying to make a game or just a regular program.

Comment: I've updated my answer just in case you don't want o use a loop. But you should read up on game programming if you're new to it. I doubt you're new to c# cause you're code shows the opposent. If it's not a game then let me know. That way I could re-evaluate your question